# Accelerometer onSensorChanged not called when screen is off

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I have a background service which is running all the times and collects sensor data.
But when the screen dims, it stops collecting the data.

I want it to collect even in this case.

My device is HTC MyTouch.
I have tried prtial wake lock, buy it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me fix this problem.

Thanks
Sowmya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708

Unfortunately no easy fix exists and the workarounds also don't always work. It seems to be fixed in Android 2.3.3 for most (if not all) devices though.

Comment: are there any work arounds apart from partila wake lock? please let me know. Thanks

Comment: This seems to work in Android 1.7... Any one knows from which version of android this was broken, any Android official link where I can find this information... Please help

Answer (score 0):

try this in oncreate method
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
this works in my app