# Accelerometer in background

Tags: android

I am in the process of developing an Android application with the intent of monitoring accelerometer data in the background. My own device is running Android 2.2. When the device is locked it no longer collects the accelerometer data. I am aware of the partial wake lock option, but due to the nature of my application it simply isn't ideal.

I have done quite a bit of intensive Googling on the matter. Some say this is a bug, that it is unintended. However, some say that it is intended. I've also read that this is fixed in 2.3.3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671106/accelerometer-onsensorchanged-not-called-when-screen-is-off). If that is the case, I will upgrade my own device. 
However, the comments on [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708) page seem to contradict that.

I am led to believe using the partial wake lock will drain a battery fast. Is there any other way I can achieve what I want to do, or does anyone have any information on some sort of fix for this problem?

Comment: Not so much an answer, but in my experience a partial wake lock isn't really that expensive - likely because the screen is still dark. According to the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html), however, maintaining a SensorEventListener is a little gluttonous (this same documentation says that you should still get SensorEvents when the scree goes off so I'd say that it is, indeed, a bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am in the process of developing an Android application with the intent of monitoring accelerometer data in the background.

That is not a good idea.

> I have done quite a bit of intensive Googling on the matter. Some say this is a bug, that it is unintended. However, some say that it is intended. I've also read that this is fixed in 2.3.3 here. If that is the case, I will upgrade my own device. However, the comments on this page seem to contradict that.

My guess is that it is up to the device manufacturer as to what the behavior is here. Also, as noted in the issue on this topic:

> As an addendum, the way it works now is that you have to acquire a partial wake lock.
> This guarantees that the CPU will not enter sleep mode and that will guarantee that
> the sensors continue sending data as expected. The underlying problem was that,
> basically, a partial wake lock would not guarantee that the sensors would continue
> running.

.

> I am led to believe using the partial wake lock will drain a battery fast.

It keeps the CPU powered on. In normal operation, the CPU is the second biggest power drain, after the screen (GPS might also be more, but usually that is powered down).

Also, as [the documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html):

> Always make sure to disable sensors you don't need, especially when your activity is paused. Failing to do so can drain the battery in just a few hours.
>
> Is there any other way I can achieve what I want to do, or does anyone have any information on some sort of fix for this problem?

There is no problem. If you want to execute code with the screen off, you have to use a partial `WakeLock`. That has nothing specifically to do with sensors -- *any* time want to execute code with the screen off, you have to use a partial `WakeLock`.